# Should one unbind UBOs after usage?

Tags: opengl-es

I render several objects with an number of drawcalls and shaders and UBOs. Currently I take the effort to unbind all UBOs I don't need with glBindBufferBase and bufferId  = 0 like people do with glBindBuffer(target,0)

Now my question is, is this really worth the effort? All the UBOs that are needed are rebound anyways before the drawcall and the shader only uses what it needs. Can there be problems like with stability or performance or once the UBO is destroyed etc.?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

> Now my question is, is this really worth the effort?

In release builds, no; it's purely busy-work which will cost CPU performance and battery-life for no functional benefit. Change states directly from the "old state" into the "new state" without bouncing via zero first. Same applies to other things too (samplers, enables, etc).

However, it generally can be useful to have force-to-zero an a debug option to use in development builds if you are debugging rendering bugs to rule our state leakage across draws.

> Can there be problems like with stability or performance or once the UBO is destroyed etc.?

The resource will only be freed when there are no remaining bindings active, so you do need to remember to clear bindings when deleting resources (but hopefully you have some sensible resource tracking already, so you should "know" this in the engine).